# Ошибка "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, android

При создании проектов в Android появляется ошибка:

> NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native

Много тем пересмотрел, но решения так и не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот класс из проекта JNA: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java . Сборка в виде jar : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna